# How do i use two aspect-ratios in a media query?

Tags: css, media-queries, aspect-ratio

Im trying to set a behaviour for different screen sizes, e.g. I want to have a set of css rules for any screen between the aspect ratio 320x560 and the aspect ratio 414x736.

I've already tried taking a similar approach as one might do if working with min-width and max-width.

Everything is on here: [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYBwbO)
There you can see that i have a working example for widths commented out, but for some reason it won't work with aspect ratio.

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 600px/495px) and (max-aspect-ratio: 1000px/800px){
    div {
    color: yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know it's the case but are px values supported? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio

Comment: @SuperDJ px values are not supported, i edited the code but the problem still remains

Comment: Hi Endrit, your example is working for me on Firefox. What browser are you testing on?

Comment: @slynagh primarily on safari, but i just tried in chrome and it doesn't seem to be working there either, maybe they aren't supported?

Comment: Endrit Your example also works on chrome. Perhaps you are expecting a different result than you are getting? When I resize my window, at a specific point the text turns yellow. It's a very narrow range, is that what you want? Perhaps you mean to target exact screen pixel dimensions?

Comment: @slynagh I think my approach to the task given to me was bad. I was creating a responsive website and i wanted to change layouts when reaching a certain pixel dimension. 
I'm currently trying a new approach, i've decided to change my layout in one way when certain widths are reached and to change the layout in some other way when certain heights are reached. 
Not sure if my new approach is better than before, but i'm having an easier time using it, feel free to give me a better suggestion for working with responsiveness, i'm pretty new to it, so any input is appreciated.

Comment: @EndritBeqiri I recently worked on a similar website and it's not an easy task. But I used your current approach as well. Keep in mind that even sites like google, gmail, facebook, etc aren't optimized for every possible aspect ratio. Keeping a set of normal aspect ratios (namely 16:9 and 9:16) and ranges of widths I find the best balance between good design, and keeping your sanity. You shouldn't be worried about it looking good if a person has their viewport resized to some unusable demensions.

Comment: @Endrit I think the issue is a misunderstanding of aspect ratio - it does not descibe exact pixel dimensions but rather the "shape" of the viewport. It is very common however to use min and max width as you have done. Remember also that you are not querying a screen's dimensions but the dimensions of the browser's window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox only works at the exact ratios for me.

A ratio is not a value on its own, rather, its the result of a computation. I don't believe any CSS engine is designed to compute the current aspect ratio and compare it between two potential values, it only works with the currently computed ratio. You would be able to accomplish this in javascript if you applied a listener to the window resize event.

To do it in CSS you would need to create multiple media queries that define a min-height, max-height, min-width, max-width along with a single ratio to create a range.

Interesting question though, never thought to try a aspect ratio range before. Would be useful to implement.

Comment: This is not true. The aspect ratios as calculated certainly do have a range, between 1.21212 and 1.25. It is between these values that Endrit's example works.

Comment: @slynagh sorry I meant the math doesn't work in CSS, since CSS doesn't dynamically compute aspect ratio math to create a comparison, fixed my answer.